# Scraping an internal web page

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, scrapy, python-requests

I have to scrape an internal web page of my organization. If I use Beautiful soap I get

**"Unauthorized access"**

I don't want to put my username/password in the source code because it will be shared across collegues. 
If I open the same web url using Firefox It doesn't not ask me to login, the only problem is when I make the same request using python script.
Is there a way to share the same session used by firefox with a python script?

I think my authentication is with my PC because if I log off deleting all cookies When i re-enter I because logged in automatically. Do you know why with my python script this doesn’t not happen?

Comment: Well, you should ask whoever is responsible for the webserver.

Comment: @KlausD. I am looking for some libraries to use to access a web page to a windows-managed credential

Answer (score 0):

When you use the browser to login to your organization, you provide your credentials and the server returns a cookie tied to your organization's domain. This cookie has an expiration and allows to use navigate your organization's site without having to login as long as the cookie is valid.

You can read about cookies here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie

Your website scraper does not need to store your credentials. First delete the cookies then, using your browser's developer tools, you can (look at the network tab):

1. Figure out if your organization uses a separate auth end point

   - If it's not evident, then you might ask the IT department
2. Use the auth endpoint to get a cookie using credentials passed in
3. See how this cookie is used by the system (look at the HTTP request/response headers)
4. Use this cookie to scrape the website
5. Share your code freely - if someone needs to scrape the website then they can either pass in their credentials, or use a curl command to get/set a valid cookie header

Answer (score 0):

1) After authenticating in your Firefox browser, make sure to get the cookie key/value.

2) Use that data in the code below :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

browser_cookies = {'your_cookie_key':'your_cookie_value'}
s = requests.Session()
r = s.get(your_url, cookies=browser_cookies)
bsoup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
```

The `requests.Session()` is for persistence.
One more tips, you could also call your script like that :

```
python3 /path/to/script/script.py cookies_key cookies_value
```

Then, get the two values with sys module. The code will be :

```
import sys
browser_cookies = {sys.argv[1]:sys.argv[2]}
```

Comment: I think my authentication is with my PC because if I log off deleting all cookies When i re-enter I because logged in automatically. Do you know why with my python script this doesn’t not happen?

Comment: Did you try with another browser ?

Comment: 1) Is your firefox setup with a proxy of some sort ? 2) Also you should watch the headers of the requests you send (with your firefox browser) when you access the authenticated page. It should give you some hints : IP address, user agent... And then you can try to put the same headers in your code and send them with the same requests where you send the cookies.